# Performance of configurable products category

Tags: configurable-product, performance, redis, ce-1.9.2.1

How can I improve performance of my category page which consists mostly of configurable products?
I have configurable products created out of cca 160 simple products (different sizes, colours and formats). If I put those products to certain category, site load will slow down to cca 40 seconds!
base url (which works at normal speed): www.malckovsvet.si
problem on this page: http://www.malckovsvet.si/oblacila/potiskani-bodiji.html
example of product (which loads normally): http://www.malckovsvet.si/oblacila/potiskani-bodiji/bodi-mami-ati-jaz.html

HW: CPU - xenon X5570  @ 2.93GHz, Ram - 2 GB (4GB peak), Disk - SSD

SW: PHP 5.5.9 with opcache, Magento CE ver. 1.9.2.1

I am thinking of implementing redis on this server, but will that help enough? What do you recommend?